# The application compiz has closed unexpectedly

Tags: unity, compiz, login, gui

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my desktop. (Pentium 4, 80 GB hard disk, 2 GB RAM, 32-bit CPU.)  And I have installed Windows XP.

I made a 40 GB partition for Windows and 40 GB for Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu and it said "installation is complete" and asked me to restart. I restarted the PC and then logged in. After 1 minute I get a message like this:

> The application compiz has closed unexpectedly.

Then I closed it. After that it just stays in a blank screen and nothing shows up.

What should I do?

Comment: Does compiz start back up after crashing?

Comment: Also, what happens if you press Ctrl+Alt+T and run `unity --replace`? Does that restore your desktop? How about `unity --reset`? How about `compiz --replace`? If pressing Ctrl+Alt+T doesn't work, try Alt+F2. If neither works, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, log on, and run `compiz --display :0 --replace`, then switch back to the GUI (Ctrl+Alt+F7). These are not really solutions, though they may help work around the problem in the short term (and may not). Their primary usefulness is diagnostic--knowing what happens when you do this may help to figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: And does this always happen? Or have you only tried logging in once?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @EliahKagan Isn't `unity --reset` deprecated and discouraged in 12.10 ?

Comment: @EliahKagan `unity --help` says it: `Reset is not supported anymore. Deprecated option`. Mahesh,  jokerdino and amithkk here on Ask Ubuntu have a GitHub repository for an  [implementation of of a unity reset](http://askubuntu.com/a/202020/8698)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in 12.10 but it may be exacerbated by the graphics sub-system on your motherboard, assuming you have a motherboard with integrated graphics from the chipset's north bridge.

It appears that the error is caused by some sort of a disconnect between Unity and certain graphics hardware. A great many people are running into this bug.

The short answer is that you need to go back to 12.04. When I gave up on 12.10 and went back to 12.04 I no longer got this error. Someone in another thread had suggested that using 2D graphics in 12.04 would fix the compiz problem but I had no issues with 3D in 12.04, in fact 2D didn't work properly.

What made no difference:

Upping the shared graphics memory: Still got the error in 12.10 but not 12.04.
Using 2D in 12.04: Actually didn't work at all, graphics was all screwy.

This error happens only with certain graphics cards.